# Cambiar Recursos de FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Estoy haciendo un calendario, usando la vista ["timeline" de FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/). Lo que quiero hacer es cambiar los "recursos" de una forma dinámica, ya que tengo ya vista de Estudiantes y la vista de Proyectos, cada uno con sus eventos correspondientes.

Intenté hacer algo así:

```
var resources = 'students';
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    resources: {
        url: 'resource-load.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'data': resources
        }
    }
});
```

Y las vistas las cambios desde un select:

```
switch (selected) {
case 'general':
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'month');
    break;
case 'students':
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'timelineDay');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option','resourceLabelText','Students');
    resources = 'students';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
    break;
case 'proyects':
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'timelineDay');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option','resourceLabelText','Proyects');
    resources = 'proyects';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
    break;
default: break;
}
```

Lo que hace que al principio carguen los estudiantes, pero cuando cambio de vista, no pasa nada.

En el StackOverflow en inglés, me dijeron que podía obtener [recursos con una función](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/resources_function/), y luego recargar el plugin, pero el problema es que no entiendo como hacer esto, ya que no he estudiado javascript tan a fondo. Si alguien pudiera explicarme como hacer esto sería ideal.

Comment: simplemente no hace nada, o en la consola te marca algún error?.

Comment: pude solucionar el problema con la ayuda de una persona en el StackOverflow en inglés. Dejaré el enlace como respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la ayuda de una persona del StackOverflow en inglés, pude solucionar el problema.

La respuesta es obtener los [recursos mediante una función](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/resources_function/) de esta manera:

```
var resources = 'students';
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    resources: function(callback) {
        getResources(function(resourceObjects) {
            callback(resourceObjects);
        });
    }
});
function getResources(handleData) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"resource-load.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'data': resources
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data) {
            handleData(data); 
        }
    });
}
```

Ya que cada vez que cambiamos las vistas, cambia el valor de `resources` y se hace una recarga de los recursos, lo que vuelve a llamar a la función con el nuevo valor de `resources`.

Aquí el enlace de la solución en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601746/change-resources-in-fullcalendar

Comment: Deberías poner la respuesta en español y dejar el enlace como referencia porque puede que algunos usuarios te marquen la respuesta como negativa, debido a que el contenido dentro de los enlaces puede cambiar o pueden quedar rotos.

Comment: Lo hice, gracias